# Short audio files

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, mp3, media

I'm trying to play a couple of short audio files (ca. 2sec) in an Android App with the Media Player. They do play, but for some of them I get a click sound at the end (which differs from file to file).

There are no click-sounds when I play it on the PC, also I tried to convert it from .mp3 in .ogg and modified the soundfiles themselves, nothing helps, I think the problem is probably the Media PLayer.

Answer (score 0):

For short audio files, like sound effects, I would use a [SoundPool](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html)

Also see this question and answer here: [The correct way to play short sounds Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656853/the-correct-way-to-play-short-sounds-android)