# Audio interrupted when updating Android seebar while playing Media Player

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am developing an app that plays music from **raw music files** and it updates seekbar once every second while the `media player` is playing. However, this is **interrupting** audio each time the seekbar is updated through **Runnable**. I've tried using Sound Pool (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17069955/play-sound-using-soundpool-example)) or creating new Thread suggested by other posts but the issue still exists. Should I be using service instead?

The following code snippet is run from a ListFragment. Thanks.

```
mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        updateProgress = false;
    }
});

seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
seekBar.setProgress(0);
updateProgress = true;

updateRunnableHandler = new Handler();
mUpdateRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (updateProgress) {
            seekBar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
            updateRunnableHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateRunnable, 1000);
        }
    }
};

updateRunnableHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateRunnable, 1000);
mediaPlayer.start();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the issue. The code needs to check if the onProgressChanged event handled by seekbar's setOnSeekBarChangeListener is from the user or not.

```
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        if (fromUser) {
            musicService.setPosition(progress);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Fantastic. This sorted mine out perfectly. Thought I had a bizarre error.