# Play specific sound when specific button is pressed

Tags: android, button, audio, android-studio

I'm really new to Android Studio, and am trying to make a simple app which plays specific sounds when a specific button is pressed. I have looked up many tutorials on YouTube, stack and other websites, but all of them seem to either give me a lot of errors or are too hard for me too understand (as I am too unexperienced).
All I have now are a lot of buttons on the screen which do nothing.

So can someone show me how to make something like this:
When button 1 is pressed, sound 1 plays, and when button 2 is pressed, sound 2 plays. (And that has to go on like that for about 20/30 buttons and sounds)

Thanks in advance, 
-Spickle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `MediaPlayer mp` object and use this in your onClick methods:

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.SoundForSpecificButton);
mp.start();
```

Then create a `raw` folder inside a `res` folder and put there your sounds.

Here is good documentation about this:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#mediaplayer

If you are having problems please put your code here for review.

Comment: Never mind my last comment, I figured that out (I think). I don't get any errors, except for one: cannot resolve symbol 'context'. What do I do?

Comment: Ah, I figured it out. I changed 'context' to 'this' (I remembered that being used in some of the videos I saw) and now it's working! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to audio for a very short duration for example a 'click' sound when you press a button look for SoundPool class in android.

[Play sound using soundpool example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17069955/play-sound-using-soundpool-example)

If you want to stream a bigger audio file you will have to implement MediaPlayer.