# What is the problem with this code ?Why is not working ,it tellls me "Illegal Start of expression","expected ;" and it points me to (View V))

Tags: android, android-sound

```
sound1= sounds.load(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.sound1,1);
```

Here is a function that want to play a sound when the `button` is clicked.

```
public void playsound1(View v ) {
 sounds.play(sound1,1.0f,1.0f,0,10f);
}
```

But i don't know why it does not working?

Comment: This may helps you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17069955/play-sound-using-soundpool-example

Answer (score 0):

In your code look above your method. You must have forgotten to put the `}` symbol to close the method right above.

Comment: Here is just a part of my code.... it is not the whole code, but i dont miss any } trust me, i dont know why my code is giving me a lot of errors because is the one and only because there are 9 methods playsound1 ... 9 and to all of them is a problem

Comment: Try formatting the code properly, you'll probably find what's missing pretty quick @BotaRafael

Comment: In android studio is formated good bro, but i dont know why it is not working.... maybe some teamviewer will help me if somebody is available to help