# How to play android sounds NOT in activity class

Tags: java, android, audio, android-activity

How can I play sound from a class that DOES NOT extend activity? I've been searching for a while and in every tutorial or answers from stackoverflow I've seen that sounds are always implemented in an activity class.

But in this case I have a class thas has the logic of my game, in which I have a gameUpdate() function; and in that function I want to make a specific sound play if something happens (for example a collision).  How can I possibly access the activity that is currently running, from this class?  Is there any way to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at SoundPool from this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656853/the-correct-way-to-play-short-sounds-android

Comment: How can you comment with 1 reputation? :p Anyway, that does not answer my question. in that example sound is played in the activity class, which I don't want

Answer (score 0):

`getActivity()` or if is inside a fragment `getFragment().getActivity()`

Or alternativelly you can make add a `Context` to your class and get the activity reference from the constructor of the class.

Ex:

```
public class MyClass {
    Context mContext();
    public MyClass(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }
```

}

and in your Activity class when you call MyClass:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass(this);
```

Inside your custom lass you can reference activity methods using its [context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html).

Comment: none of these functions getActivity() or getFragment().getActivity() were recognised in my class, nor in the view class

the error is "function is undefined for the type *Classname* "

Comment: If you are not inside a fragment or an activity you need a Context. Add a Context to your constructor and pass it from the activity or fragment. You can also pass it through a button as explained in the answer from @Abdul Fair

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get the current `Activity` instance or context you need to pass it to your other classes so that you can use it. For example:

```
class ABC extends Activity
{
    public void onCreate(Bundle b)
    {
        XYZ xyz=new XYZ(this); // Sending the current Activity instance
    }
}   

class XYZ
{
    ABC activity;
    public XYZ(ABC activity)
    {
        this.activity = activity; //Now you can use it in this class
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, i thought about that approach thing is, I have some classes chained (the activity creates a view, the view creates this class i was talking about), so I wanted to avoid "ping-ponging" my activity in all constructors. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

So you actually just need a `Context`, not specifically an `Activity` (which *is* a `Context`). I would recommend that the class that should play sounds has a constructor which requires a `Context`. Keep a reference, not directly to the `Context` that you receive, but to the Application context using `getApplicationContext()` to get a `Context` that is safe to retain without the risk of memory leaks.

```
public class MySoundPlayingClass {
    private final Context mContext;

    public MySoundPlayingClass(Context ctx) {
        // Since ctx could be an Activity, and this class
        // could exist outside of the lifecycle of the Activity,
        // grab the Application context to get a safe reference.
        mContext = ctx.getApplicationContext();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a Util class and do something similar to below one. You can pass the context (it can be Activity instance) and the resource id to play it

Usage:

```
Util.play(context, R.raw.soundFile);
```

Sample Util class:

```
public class Util {
   public static void play(final Context context, int resource) {
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, resource);
    if (null != mp) {
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.release();
            }
        });
        mp.start();
    }
  }
}
```