# To play a sound while displaying a displaying a dialogue

Tags: android, audio, popup, dialog

Hi I would like to play a sound while invoking a dialogue box. Can anyone please help me achieving it.

Comment: at last I've found an answer for my question. 
please refer the below link for more help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656853/the-correct-way-to-play-short-sounds-android?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

Try by making the dialogue as a dialogue activity. Start the audio in on create and stop the audio at on destroy . Use media player for playing audio.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you please provide any sample code.